# Exporting Maven Archetype from Local Repository

Tags: maven, repository, maven-archetype

I have a Maven archetype that I created myself from one of my projects and installed in my own local Maven repository. From Eclipse I am able to create new projects using this archetype and I obviously have access to the archetype's "installed" files (the ones that are placed in the repository after the install).

The problem is that now I want to share the archetype to a colleague, but after I created it and installed it to my local repository, I deleted the "installer" files (the ones that are generated in the generated-sources/archetype folder of my source project), so now I only have the archetype installed in my repository and I don't know how to export it in order to share it with someone else.

I could create a new archetype, but I put so much effort and spent several hours in doing that in the first place, so I would like to find out exporting the current archetype is possible, and if so, how can I do it?

**EDIT**

Asked in a different way, can I take the "installed" files from my local repository and put them in other repository, and have Maven recognize them as an Archetype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we ended up doing was to zip the repository archetype folder and send it to my colleague, who then performed these steps:

1. Unzip the archetype folder file to the root of his local Maven repository.
2. Execute the command ´mvn archetype:crawl´.

That was it. He was able to use the archetype for creating new projects.